# Problem Installing mysql-workbench on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mysql-workbench, ubuntu-19.04

It says it is not available in any source. Tried using the debian provided by oracle. It says libssl versions are incompatible. Any help in this regard.

Comment: I mean, why the downvotes? Can I atleast have an explanation. 19.04 is released recently and I am trying it out and posting bugs/incompatibility. Please at least have the courtesy to say what is wrong with this question. 

mysql-workbench ins not avaliable in the apt repos, nor in software center, the deb file is giving errors.

Comment: This is a valid question. There is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now, mysql workbench is **available for ubuntu 19.04**.
You can manually install after downloading the file.

**Step 1:**
Direct download link- 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=488567

OR

Visit here select your OS then download as per OS version
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

**Step 2:**
sudo apt install file_path_of_downloaded_workbench

Finish!!

Comment: Good to see Oracle finally released an official version. BTW it keeps the old configurations, like we could expect it to.

Comment: Anyways, I migrated to datagrip.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by installing the libzip package, directly from the deb package. I found at https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb.html. Download and install libzip4, then install mysql-workbench from the apt or deb package, whichever you prefer.

Comment: workbench is not available in apt for Ubuntu 19.04 as of now. You might be installing it on 18.10 on which it works smoothly.

Comment: Yeah, really, install by .deb or install repositories by https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Comment: I got this `E: Unable to locate package libzip4`

Answer (score 3):

on Ubuntu 19

1)I had to, preceding it on Ubuntu 19, also install manually a library libzip https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb.html

2) then manually selecting on a download page deb package for mysql workbench https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

then install deb packages via a standard apt installer in a Downloads dir

`sudo apt install ./libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb`

and downloaded workbench deb package

`sudo apt install ./mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source code from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/, compile it and install it. I did it that way and it works perfectly for me. I had to install several package dependencies and review some basic compiler details, but in the end the result was successful. Follow the INSTALL file instructions and consider removing the Werror option from the CMakeLists.txt. Download antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar from web, and then run:

```
cmake -Wno-dev -DWITH_ANTLR_JAR='path_to_antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar' -Wno-error
make
sudo make install
```

[screenshoot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q2lg.png)

[screenshoot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZALN.jpg)

Comment: How did you solved for this
```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find ANTLR4 (missing: ANTLR4_LIBRARY ANTLR4_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  build/cmake/Modules/FindANTLR4.cmake:41 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:91 (find_package)
```

Answer (score 1):

UBUNTU 19.04 disco dingo -> mysql-workbench install steps:

1. add mysql complete source list from: https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
2. install libs: `sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0 libpcre++*`
3. add debian source list on "/etc/apt/sources.list" :

```
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
```

4. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y`
5. `sudo apt-get install mysql-utilities mysql-common mysql-community*`
6. `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench (finish!!)`

works here!

Comment: This should have more votes. If dependencies are missing when installing the workbench deb then the step 2 is what we need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of workbench does not support Ubuntu 19.04 and version for 19.10 will not work.

You have to download specific workbench version supported by 19.04 from the archive.

- Visit https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/
- Select product version 8.0.17,
- download and install package `mysql-workbench-community_8.0.17-1ubuntu19.04_amd64.deb`

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04.01 and this worked for me. I installed 8.0.17 version

Answer (score 0):

check out gdebi

gdebi is a tool resolving & installing dependencies, for more info http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gdebi.1.html

Answer (score 0):

1) Install libzip4

```
curl -OL http://launchpadlibrarian.net/260671111/libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libzip4_1.1.2-1.1_amd64.deb
```

2) Then install MySQL workbench on Ubuntu 19.04 by running the commands:

```
curl -OL https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench- 
community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.16-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

3) Install missing dependencies (**libatkmm-1.6-1v5, libglibmm-2.4-1v5, libgtk2.0-0, libgtkmm-3.0-1v5, libpcrecpp0v5, libpython2.7, libsigc++-2.0-0v5, libtinfo5)** by this command.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Download the .deb file from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)

Install it using command

```
dpkg -i *.deb。
```

Answer (score 0):

**Now MYSQL-WORKBENCH for Ubuntu-19.04(Disco) is available.**

To install mysql workbench form command line you need add dependencies manually.

- Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and Append following lines:

> `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main`
>
> `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic main universe`

- `sudo apt-get update`
- Download mysql-workbench from '[Mysql Workbench-19.04 for Ubuntu](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)' and install by giving execute permission to `mysql-workbench-community_8.0.17-1ubuntu19.04_amd64.deb` file.

Now it should work. :)