# How to get access to Mysql in Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I installed Mysql server following the guide.

In terminal:
`mysql -u root`

and receiving error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Additionally, I cannot `sudo apt install mysql-workbench` (it is not found in repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo mysql -u root -p`.

I believe it's some kind of security feature or something like that (not entirely sure). But with su/sudo rights, you can connect to the socket. The `-p` option will ask for password input

***Added after a comment about symbols in the password:***

My assumption is that the encoding of these characters isn't correct (ASCII connection, and non-ASCII charaters). Try connection with the following command, as stated in [this SO answer by Martin Taleski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788223)

```
sudo mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -p
```

You can set this as a default in the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file.

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Comment: same: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Did you setup a password during the setup? If thadd (I believe)

Comment: thanks much, it works now. BUT, why so hard? I have to do that every time?...

Comment: and what could you say about installing workbench?:)

Comment: @andrew17, you can change it in the my.cnf file, so that you don't have to define it every time.

Comment: @andrew17 did you do a `sudo apt update` before trying to install the package? Which ubuntu version are you on?

Comment: @andrew17, it seems like you have to manually download the file, and then install it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553970) for more details